# Running a windows 7 C++/Cli application in windows xp

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-xp, c++-cli

I have created a application in c++/cli in visual studio 2010 in windows 7 environment.It works perfectly well.But I got to know about the xp platform only later.Now I want to install my application in windows xp.Now I feel I got in to a big problem. Do I need to redo the application again in windows xp using native c++ or can i install .net in xp and execute the application. Please shed some light..

Thanks

Comment: Sure, just install framework for which your application is targeted to.

Comment: @arrowdodger ..thanks.. but i develope in windows 7.. will it be a problem..?

Comment: Well, Test it on your target platform (Both Installation and Execution)!

Answer (score 0):

No need to redo everything.. Installing .Net 3.5 or 4 (depending on what you used in VS2010) and the dependencies for the native code (the crt redistributable for example) should do the trick.

Note however that some functions of kernel.dll from Windows vista/7 are simply non-existent in Windows XP. I once spent quite some time figuring out `InitializeSRWLock` does not exist for XP. Solving such problems can be quite hard so make sure you have a machine running XP to test everything on.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that you are linking the runtime libraries statically (or as stijn said, install the required dependencies if linking dynamically) so that All library routines used in the program are copied into the final EXE file.

> Under Configuration Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime
>   Library -> MultiThreaded (/MT)
>
> In addition, if using MFC:
>
> Configuration Properties, General, Use of MFC -> Use MFC in a Static
>   Library
>
> In addition, if using ATL:
>
> Configuration Properties, Genera, Use of ATL -> Static Link to ATL

Refer: [Static linking in vs2010 run-time](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/845617aa-ab76-4fe1-a658-d020828598b8)

Comment: Please tell me the reason for downvote. Am I missing something here? as C++/CLI can have both managed and unmanaged code, Isn't these applicable?

Comment: Maybe because it is not required to link statically? Dynamic linking works as well..

Comment: As per my knowlege if we use dynamic linking of C Runtime, MSVCP80.DLL is needed which by default will not be present in Windows XP. ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: which is why, in my answer, I say it is needed to install the crt redistributable so MSVCP/MSVCRT etc dlls get installed

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that the first time I read. -ve vote btw is rude. Atleast It contained a bit more specific info. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: for the record, it wasn't me who downvoted :] I'll upvote you for giving a more complete answer..

Comment: I never meant that its you. I only wanted the one who down-voted to point out mistakes before doing it. Thanks for the upvote :)